# ERC20 TRANSFER function error error = false transaction

Tags: erc-20, smart-contract-wallets, transfer, presale

Want to use erc20 function transfer to transfer erc20
Made contract referring this video
https://youtu.be/-5j6Ho0Bkfk

```
function transfererc()payable public{
  Token token = Token(address);
  token.transfer(msg.sender,100);
} //But not working
```

Tried with external & payable both
False transaction error.

Answer (score 0):

`payable` means, "send me money or you can't run this function". So, I guess you didn't send money while calling the function. And I think you function doesn't need to be a payable function. So, here is a basic implementation:

```
function transferERC(address _to, uint256 _amount) public {
  Token(token).transfer(_to, _amount);
}
```